# JAX-WS Mutual Auth Failure after ClientKeyExchange

Tags: java, jax-ws, x509, mutual-authentication

**The short of it....**

I have a JAX-WS service residing on a web server using SSL and requiring mutual authentication.

First to test that mutual authentication is working properly, I import the client certificate into the browser.  I then point the browser to the protected site and it successfully connects and retrieves content.

Then I wrote the java code to connect to the service on the same web site.  I import the same certificate into a java keystore file (jks), I receive a TLSv1 Alert: fatal, handshake_failure.

I did a

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake
```

and found that the **ClientHello** and **ServerHello** were successfull.  Then it proceeds to do the **ClientKeyExchange**, and I see the SESSION KEYGEN.  Then it goes to **CertificateVerify** and that is when the fatal, handshake_failure occurs.

I am at a loss for why the browser works and the java application does not.

I am running on Java 1.6.0_45, though I have tried this same code on Java 7 to the same result.

See below for more details.

---

**The long of it....**

This is long, I include my code for loading the key and truststores and I finally include the javax.net.debug output.

To support the loading of the keystore and truststore dynamically, I created a Custom SocketFactory.

```
    public abstract class AbstractSSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AbstractSSLSocketFactory.class);
protected AbstractSocketFactoryAdapter adapter = null;

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket arg0, String arg1, int arg2, boolean arg3)
        throws IOException {
    return this.adapter.getFactory().createSocket(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
}

@Override
public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
    String[] cipherSuites = null;
    try {
        cipherSuites = this.adapter.getFactory().getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }
    catch (ServiceSecurityException e) {
        logger.error("There was an error retrieving the SSLSocketFactory", e);
    }

    return cipherSuites;
}

@Override
public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
    String[] cipherSuites = null;
    try {
        cipherSuites = this.adapter.getFactory().getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }
    catch (ServiceSecurityException e) {
        logger.error("There was an error retrieving the SSLSocketFactory", e);
    }

    return cipherSuites;
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String arg0, int arg1) throws IOException,
        UnknownHostException {
    return this.adapter.getFactory().createSocket(arg0, arg1);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress arg0, int arg1) throws IOException {
    return this.adapter.getFactory().createSocket(arg0, arg1);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String arg0, int arg1, InetAddress arg2, int arg3)
        throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return this.adapter.getFactory().createSocket(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress arg0, int arg1, InetAddress arg2,
        int arg3) throws IOException {
    return this.adapter.getFactory().createSocket(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);
}
}
```

The adapter, which is abstract, is as follows:

```
    public abstract class AbstractSocketFactoryAdapter {
private SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = null;

protected abstract String getProtocol() throws ServiceSecurityException;

protected abstract KeyManagerFactory getKeyManagerFactory() throws ServiceSecurityException;

protected abstract TrustManagerFactory getTrustManagerFactory() throws ServiceSecurityException;

public SSLSocketFactory getFactory() throws ServiceSecurityException {
    if (this.socketFactory == null ) {
        // Create a new socket factory
        try {
            // Retrieve the KeyManagerFactory from the implementing class
            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = this.getKeyManagerFactory();

            //  Retrieve the TrustManagerFactory
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = this.getTrustManagerFactory();

            //  Retrieve the Protocol
            String protocol = this.getProtocol();

            // Create the SSL Context to create the Socket Factory
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance(protocol);

            KeyManager[] keyManagers = null;
            if ( keyManagerFactory != null ) {
                keyManagers = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();
            }

            TrustManager[] trustManagers = null;
            if ( trustManagerFactory != null ) {
                trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
            }

            // Associate the KeyManagerFactory with the SSLContext
            //      if the keyManagers and/or trustManagers are null then 
            //      the jvm default is used for the respective manager 
            context.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());

            // cache the socket factory for later use
            this.socketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new ServiceSecurityException(e);
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            throw new ServiceSecurityException(e);
        }
    }

    return this.socketFactory;
}
}
```

The concrete implementation of the adapter is:  (In this test case, I am loading the key and trust stores from disk, but ultimately we plan on storing them in a database as blobs.)

```
    public class SocketFactoryFileAdapter extends AbstractSocketFactoryAdapter {
private static final String DEFAULT_KEY_STORE_TYPE      = "JKS";
private static final String DEFAULT_TRUST_STORE_TYPE    = "JKS";
private static final String DEFAULT_PROTOCOL            = "TLS";
private final String        keyStoreType;
private final String        trustStoreType;
private final String        protocol;
private final String        keyStoreFileName;
private final String        keyStorePassword;
private final String        trustStoreFileName;
private final String        trustStorePassword;

public SocketFactoryFileAdapter(String keyStoreFileName,
        String keyStorePassword,
        String trustStoreFileName,
        String trustStorePassword) {
    this(   keyStoreFileName,
            keyStorePassword,
            SocketFactoryFileAdapter.DEFAULT_KEY_STORE_TYPE,
            trustStoreFileName,
            trustStorePassword,
            SocketFactoryFileAdapter.DEFAULT_TRUST_STORE_TYPE,
            SocketFactoryFileAdapter.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
}

public SocketFactoryFileAdapter(String keyStoreFileName,
        String keyStorePassword,
        String keyStoreType,
        String trustStoreFileName,
        String trustStorePassword,
        String trustStoreType,
        String protocol) {
    this.keyStoreFileName = keyStoreFileName;
    this.keyStorePassword = keyStorePassword;
    this.keyStoreType = keyStoreType;
    this.trustStoreFileName = trustStoreFileName;
    this.trustStorePassword = trustStorePassword;
    this.trustStoreType = trustStoreType;
    this.protocol = protocol;
}

@Override
protected KeyManagerFactory getKeyManagerFactory() throws ServiceSecurityException {
    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = null;

    // If the keystore file name is null or 0 length, do not create a new factory
    if (this.keyStoreFileName != null && keyStoreFileName.length() > 0) {
        try {
            // Create a Key Manager Factory
            keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

            // Create the KeyStore
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(this.keyStoreType);

            // Load the KeyStore from disk
            InputStream keyInput = new FileInputStream(this.keyStoreFileName);
            keyStore.load(keyInput, this.keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
            keyInput.close();

            // Initialize the Key Manager Factory
            keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, this.keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new ServiceSecurityException(e);
        }
        catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            throw new ServiceSecurityException(e);
        }
        catch (CertificateException e) {
            throw new ServiceSecurityException(e);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ServiceSecurityException(e);
        }
        catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            throw new ServiceSecurityException(e);
        }
    }

    return keyManagerFactory;
}

@Override
protected TrustManagerFactory getTrustManagerFactory() throws ServiceSecurityException {

    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = null;
    // If the keystore file name is null or 0 length, do not create a new factory
    if (this.trustStoreFileName != null && trustStoreFileName.length() > 0) {
        try {
            // Create a Trust Manager Factory
            trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

            // Create the KeyStore
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(this.trustStoreType);

            // Load the TrustStore from disk
            InputStream trustInput = new FileInputStream(this.trustStoreFileName);
            trustStore.load(trustInput, this.trustStorePassword.toCharArray());
            trustInput.close();

            // Initialize the Trust Manager Factory
            trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new ServiceSecurityException(e);
        }
        catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            throw new ServiceSecurityException(e);
        }
        catch (CertificateException e) {
            throw new ServiceSecurityException(e);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ServiceSecurityException(e);
        }
    }

    return trustManagerFactory;
}

public String getKeyStoreType() {
    return this.keyStoreType;
}

public String getTrustStoreType() {
    return this.trustStoreType;
}

@Override
public String getProtocol() {
    return this.protocol;
}
}
```

Then I have a class which puts the SSL Socket Factory into the JAX-WS context for the developer.

```
    public class SecureFileWebServiceProxy extends AbstractSecureWebServiceProxy {
public SecureFileWebServiceProxy(Class<?> serviceImplementationClass,
        String keyStoreFileName,
        String keyStorePassword,
        String trustStoreFileName,
        String trustStorePassword) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    this(serviceImplementationClass, new FileSSLSocketFactory(  keyStoreFileName,
                                                                keyStorePassword,
                                                                trustStoreFileName,
                                                                trustStorePassword));
}

public SecureFileWebServiceProxy(Class<?> serviceImplementationClass,
        String keyStoreFileName,
        String keyStorePassword,
        String keyStoreType,
        String trustStoreFileName,
        String trustStorePassword,
        String trustStoreType,
        String protocol) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    this(serviceImplementationClass, new FileSSLSocketFactory(  keyStoreFileName,
                                                                keyStorePassword,
                                                                keyStoreType,
                                                                trustStoreFileName,
                                                                trustStorePassword,
                                                                trustStoreType,
                                                                protocol));
}

private SecureFileWebServiceProxy(Class<?> serviceImplementationClass, SSLSocketFactory factory) throws InstantiationException,
        IllegalAccessException {
    super(serviceImplementationClass, factory);
}
}
```

This is the concreate Service Proxy:

```
public class SecureFileWebServiceProxy extends AbstractSecureWebServiceProxy {
public SecureFileWebServiceProxy(Class<?> serviceImplementationClass,
        String keyStoreFileName,
        String keyStorePassword,
        String trustStoreFileName,
        String trustStorePassword) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    this(serviceImplementationClass, new FileSSLSocketFactory(  keyStoreFileName,
                                                                keyStorePassword,
                                                                trustStoreFileName,
                                                                trustStorePassword));
}

public SecureFileWebServiceProxy(Class<?> serviceImplementationClass,
        String keyStoreFileName,
        String keyStorePassword,
        String keyStoreType,
        String trustStoreFileName,
        String trustStorePassword,
        String trustStoreType,
        String protocol) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    this(serviceImplementationClass, new FileSSLSocketFactory(  keyStoreFileName,
                                                                keyStorePassword,
                                                                keyStoreType,
                                                                trustStoreFileName,
                                                                trustStorePassword,
                                                                trustStoreType,
                                                                protocol));
}

private SecureFileWebServiceProxy(Class<?> serviceImplementationClass, SSLSocketFactory factory) throws InstantiationException,
        IllegalAccessException {
    super(serviceImplementationClass, factory);
}

}
```

And finally putting it all together, I call the service...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String keyStoreFileName = "keystores/keystore.jks";
    String keyStorePassword = "changeit";
    String trustStoreFileName = "keystores/keystore.jks";
    String trustStorePassword = "changeit";
    SecureFileWebServiceProxy proxy  = null;
    try {
        proxy = new SecureFileWebServiceProxy(SampleWebServiceService.class, keyStoreFileName, keyStorePassword, "JKS", trustStoreFileName, trustStorePassword, "JKS", "TLS");
    }
    catch ( Throwable th ) {
        logger.fatal("There was an error creating the service factory", th);
        return;
    }

    SampleWebService service = null;

    try {
        service = proxy.getPort(SampleWebService.class);
    }
    catch ( Throwable th ) {
        logger.fatal("There was an error creating the service", th);
        return;
    }

    try {
        String rvalue = service.testMethod("test");
        logger.debug("The service returned the value: " + rvalue);
    }
    catch ( Throwable th ) {
        logger.fatal("There was an error calling the service", th);
    }
}
```

---

Here is the output of the debug, data modified because we are using real certs not self signed...

```
keyStore is : 
keyStore type is : jks
keyStore provider is : 
init keystore
init keymanager of type SunX509
trustStore is: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\lib\security\cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
adding as trusted cert:

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
***
found key for : ALIAS_ONE
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=mycn, OU=myou, 
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = xxxxx

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: xxx
  public exponent: xxx
  Validity: [From: Tue Jun 25 06:48:52 EDT 2013,
           To: Wed Aug 27 05:12:07 EDT 2014]
  Issuer: CN=Trusted CA, OU=CA OU, O=CA O, C=US
  SerialNumber: [    xxx

Certificate Extensions: 9
[1]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.1
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ca.url, 
   accessMethod: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.2
   accessLocation: URIName: http://gtssldv-aia.geotrust.com/gtssldv.crt]
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
]

]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: xxx]
]]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [xxx]
[PolicyQualifierInfo: [
  qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1
]]  ]
]

[6]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
  clientAuth
]

[7]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

[8]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: mycn
]

[9]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:

]
***
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=mycn, OU=myou, 
  Issuer:  CN=GeoTrust DV SSL CA, OU=Domain Validated SSL, O=GeoTrust Inc., C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x6f6aa
  Valid from Tue Jun 25 06:48:52 EDT 2013 until Wed Aug 27 05:12:07 EDT 2014

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1373718630 bytes = { 45, 50, 83, 121, 185, 87, 15, 156, 174, 186, 215, 252, 210, 107, 14, 19, 172, 248, 56, 25, 231, 241, 37, 54, 112, 176, 190, 36 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 75
main, WRITE: SSLv2 client hello message, length = 101
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 81
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: -1105040847 bytes = { 16, 23, 184, 87, 110, 87, 29, 130, 248, 27, 222, 32, 33, 115, 97, 142, 220, 156, 82, 25, 208, 181, 219, 152, 205, 115, 123, 184 }
Session ID:  {69, 58, 206, 144, 22, 133, 165, 252, 186, 223, 39, 102, 91, 170, 133, 90, 27, 58, 195, 5, 57, 147, 222, 112, 205, 227, 143, 154, 228, 220, 68, 100}
Cipher Suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Created:  [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA]
** SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 1406
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=mycn, OU=myou, 
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = xxx

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: xxx
  public exponent: xxx
  Validity: [From: Tue Jun 25 06:48:52 EDT 2013,
           To: Wed Aug 27 05:12:07 EDT 2014]
  Issuer: CN=Trusted CA, OU=CA OU, O=CA O, C=US
  SerialNumber: [    06f6aa]

Certificate Extensions: 9
[1]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.1
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ca.url, 
   accessMethod: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.2
   accessLocation: URIName: http://gtssldv-aia.geotrust.com/gtssldv.crt]
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 8C F4 D9 93 0A 47 BC 00   A0 4A CE 4B 75 6E A0 B6  .....G...J.Kun..
0010: B0 B2 7E FC                                        ....
]

]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: xxx]
]]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [2.16.840.1.113733.1.7.54]
[PolicyQualifierInfo: [
  qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1

]]  ]
]

[6]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
  clientAuth
]

[7]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

[8]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: mycn
]

[9]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:

]
***
Found trusted certificate:
[
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=mycn, OU=myou, 
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = xxx

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: xxx
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Tue Jun 25 06:48:52 EDT 2013,
           To: Wed Aug 27 05:12:07 EDT 2014]
  Issuer: CN=Trusted CA, OU=CA OU, O=CA O, C=US
  SerialNumber: [    06f6aa]

Certificate Extensions: 9
[1]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.1
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ca.url, 
   accessMethod: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.2
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ca.url/ca.crt]
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
]

]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: xxx]
]]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [2.16.840.1.113733.1.7.54]
[PolicyQualifierInfo: [

]]  ]
]

[6]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
  clientAuth
]

[7]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

[8]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: mycn
]

[9]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:

]
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 8
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA
Cert Authorities:
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 4
*** ServerHelloDone
matching alias: ALIAS_ONE
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=mycn, OU=myou, 
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = xxx

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: xxx
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Tue Jun 25 06:48:52 EDT 2013,
           To: Wed Aug 27 05:12:07 EDT 2014]
  Issuer: CN=Trusted CA, OU=CA OU, O=CA O, C=US
  SerialNumber: [    xxx]

Certificate Extensions: 9
[1]: ObjectId: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 Criticality=false
AuthorityInfoAccess [
  [
   accessMethod: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.1
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ca.url, 
   accessMethod: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.2
   accessLocation: URIName: http://ca.url/ca.crt]
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
]

]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:false
  PathLen: undefined
]

[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.31 Criticality=false
CRLDistributionPoints [
  [DistributionPoint:
     [URIName: xxx]
]]

[5]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [2.16.840.1.113733.1.7.54]
[PolicyQualifierInfo: [
  qualifierID: 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.2.1

]]  ]
]

[6]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  serverAuth
  clientAuth
]

[7]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  DigitalSignature
  Key_Encipherment
]

[8]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: mycn
]

[9]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
]
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:

]
***
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 1668
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:

CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:

Server Nonce:

Master Secret:

Client MAC write Secret:

Server MAC write Secret:

Client write key:

Server write key:

... no IV used for this cipher
*** CertificateVerify
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 262
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { xxx }
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 36
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
2014-01-23 11:50:47,034 FATAL (Main.java:main():70)  - There was an error calling the service
com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:134)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:135)
    at com.sun.xml.xwss.XWSSClientPipe.process(XWSSClientPipe.java:118)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:115)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:595)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:554)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:539)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:436)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:248)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:135)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:109)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:118)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.testMethod(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:66)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:136)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1822)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1004)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:434)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1031)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(HttpClientTransport.java:122)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: I even tried tried modifying the jvm with javax.net.ssl.keyStore, etc... And not using the the code to dynamically load it.  The debug output is identical.

Comment: I did a wireshark capture of the exchange and I see that I am getting an Alert Message, Level fatal 2, Handshake Failure (code 40).  This happens right after Encrypted Handshake Message.  this is looking more and more like there is something wrong with my JKS, but I cannot tell what.